# What is the name & purpose of 2 wooden poles with a net around it in a farm?

Tags: agriculture

I noticed that inside an enclosed farm, there were multiple structures erected. They looked like 2 wooden poles/sticks with circular net around it. I wanted to know what’s the name for it and what’s the purpose behind erecting it?

Comment: Try gardening & landscaping maybe? https://gardening.stackexchange.com/